# Where have all the cypherpunks gone?

Tags: encryption

In 1992, cypherpunks was created as a mailing list for activists advocating for cryptography.

Arguably, the cypherpunks mailing list was the foundation for the movement and the centre of it all.

However, the original list is dead. All I really know of is the moderated cryptography list.

Where have all the modern cypherpunks gone?

Comment: The newsgroup sci.crypt is still alive.

Comment: @Nils Pipenbrinck: yes, but the traffic on sci.crypt (URL:  news:sci.crypt  or  news//:sci.crypt ) has lowered, and I now seldom read something interesting. I am 100% bought by the editing capabilities and relatively high quality of the material we get here. My main fear is about long-term archival, but that's for [meta](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

A few relevant mailing lists:

- [cypherpunks@cpunks.org](https://cpunks.org/mailman/listinfo/cypherpunks)
- [cryptography@metzdowd.com](http://www.metzdowd.com/mailman/listinfo/cryptography) (moderated)
- [cryptography@randombit.net](http://lists.randombit.net/mailman/listinfo/cryptography)
- [liberationtech@lists.stanford.edu](https://mailman.stanford.edu/mailman/listinfo/liberationtech)

Other crypto mailing lists with a narrower technical focus:

- [messaging@moderncrypto.org](https://moderncrypto.org/mailman/listinfo/messaging)
- [curves@moderncrypto.org](https://moderncrypto.org/mailman/listinfo/curves)
- [cfrg@irtf.org](https://www.ietf.org/mailman/listinfo/cfrg)
- [tls@ietf.org](https://www.ietf.org/mailman/listinfo/tls)